# how to create table in MySQL using sequel with int(3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel, mysql2, ruby-grape

How to create `int(3)` columns in MySQL using the sequel gem?

I tried the following, but the column is still created with the type `int(11)` in MySQL.

```
DB.create_table :table1 do
  Integer(:a, :size => 3)
end
```

Comment: in migration or plain sql?

Comment: plain sql. i want to create table in mysql using sequel, with integer size with some no.

Comment: `DB.run "CREATE TABLE users (name int(255) NOT NULL, age INT(3) NOT NULL)"` try this

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the size (length in bytes) of the column using the `size` option is **[not supported](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/483) for Integer column types in Sequel**. The author of the gem advises to use a string definition of the column.

For this to work, you'll also need to use the [other style of defining schema in sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/schema_modification.rdoc#column-types), using the `column` methods, like in the following rewrite of your creation sample:

```
DB.create_table(:table1) do
  column :a, 'integer(3)'
end
```